# how to use different background color for radio button

Tags: css, angular

```
<td  align='center' *ngFor="let items of  QuestionMaster.Ratings let i=index">
        <!-- Added "required" here, remove if you do not need it! -->
        <input type="radio" [value]="items.rateno"  name="{{item.question1}}" ngModel required />                  
    </td>
```

css

```
 input[type='radio'] {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
  border:1px solid darkgray;
  border-radius:50%;
  outline:none;
 box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px gray inset;
 }
 input[type='radio']:hover {
  box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px orange inset;
}
input[type='radio']:before {
content:'';
display:block;
width:60%;
height:60%;
margin: 20% auto;    
 border-radius:50%;    
}
 input[type='radio']:checked:before {
background:orange;
}
```

image

[image]

I want to set different color depends on content

example:

if radio button `Good selected` then   `radio button color should be red`

if radio button `Very Good selected`  then  `radio button color should be green`

if radio button `Excellent selected`  then  `radio button color should be orange`

> Note: I want to change color on checked radio only means if radio button good selected then color is red instead of orange like in image

Comment: use `ngClass` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

Comment: @MorKadosh  please explain how to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/vadimb/n5pjgev6/420/

The key point is to use reference variable `#name` to get the current value for updating form:

```
<label [ng-class]="{good: sel1.checked}">
   <input #sel1 type="radio" name="name1" [(ng-model)]="data.sel1"> Good
</label>
```

To set the correct class - we use `ngClass` directive with taking status from concrete reference variable.

Comment: fiddler example not changing  color

Comment: not label color I want radio button color check image like that

Answer (score 1):

With ngClass in Angular 2 you can apply a class to an element based on a condition, specified by an expression that results in a truthy/falsey.

```
<input type="radio" [value]="items.rateno"  name="{{item.question1}}" ngModel required [ngClass]="{ good: expression, verygood: expression, excellent: expression}" />
```

I can't tell from the code you posted what expression would give you the results you are looking for but you could for example test for the presence of a variable by replacing "expression" with the variable name. You could also test for the value of some variable like this {cssClass: variable === 'string'"}.

Once you have a unique class applied to each radio button, simply target those classes with your CSS:

```
input[type='radio'].excellent {
   background:orange;
}
```

Comment: when I tried solution it shows like **Can't bind to 'ngclass' since it isn't a known property**